# Why is the online enrolling of ZKTeco time attendance terminal returning result=6?

Tags: c#, zkteco

I am using a *ZKTeco Time Attendance Terminal* with these details:

> Model: `K50-A`
>   Platform: `JZ4725_TFT`
>   Firmware: `Ver 6.60 May 25 2018`
>   FP Algorithm: `10`

I can perform almost all operations found in the demo application, except the online enrolling. Whenever I try to enroll fingerprints to a user, the device just blinks an this error shows up in the application status:

```
Enroll finger failed. Result=6
```

From what I found for the `GetLastError()` method in the SDK doc, it probably means, `Wrong Password`. But I have already connected with the device with `commKey` and all other operations are working.

What error is it? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Share the program you used for connecting the device, and SDK call used for enrolling fingerprint in the comment to have a better understanding. Anyway, your issue looks like firmware issue. You have to get your vendor to give you the updated firmware as per your mother board version (ZKMxxx/ZLMxxx). The bad thing is, your vendor might not have this knowledge to understand at SDK level. So, all the best.